# error in changing color of rectangles in an array Rectangle[] C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've decleared rectancle array

`Rectangle[] rec = new Rectangle[size];`

also decleared those function

```
 public void process()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {

            rec[k].Fill = Brushes.Green;
        }
    }
 private void createRectangle()
    {

        int width = 32;
        int height = 32;
        int top = 20;
        int left = 20;
        for (int j = 0; j < banks; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= size ; i++)
            {
                rec[i].Name = "0" + i.ToString();
                rec[i].Width = width;
                rec[i].Height = height;
                rec[i].Fill = Brushes.Red;
                canvas.Children.Add(rec[i]);
                Canvas.SetTop(rec[i], top);
                Canvas.SetLeft(rec[i], left);
                left += 40;
            }
            left = 20;
            top += 50;
        }
    }
```

when calling those methods in main

```
createRectangle();
        process();
```

What `process();` does is that change the fill color to Red after drawing the rectangles 
consider `size = 5` and `banks = 3`

what i am trying to achieve is that i want to change the color of some rectangles, and i get an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in FYP (Improved).exe"
i don't know what am i doing wrong in the code.
please elaborate the soloution

Comment: change `for (int i = 1; i <= size ; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)`. Index starts at position `0`

Comment: i've already tried this, But same error occors @FlatEric

Comment: then you should use the debugger to find out in which line the exception happens

Comment: Exception occurs `for(int i = 0; i< size ; i++){rec[i].Name = "0" + i.ToString();` @FlatEric

Comment: you are using "3" in this line, and variable size on all others -  for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++), this could be the reason

Comment: Funny question but i must make sure you did it, did you add new rectangles to the array? Its not enough to just declare the size of the array..   for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  rec[i] = new Rectangle();

Comment: i've edit the question and the `size = 3` @ZivWeissman

Comment: the exception occurs on what "i" ?

Comment: tried `rec[i] = new Rectangle()'` but still the same Exception @Adi

Comment: `i` is the index in `Rectangle rec = new Rectangle[size];`@ZivWeissman

Comment: Yeah i can see that, what i meant was what is the value of i when the exception occurs?

Comment: The location of 'for' i gave you should be before calling createRectangle OR you can call rec[i] = new Rectangle(); before the line rec[i] = "0" .... In createRectangle()

Comment: the exception occurs at the first iteration on " for loop" @ZivWeissman,  the location of `rec[i] = new Rectangle()` is before `rec[i].Name = "0" + i.ToString();` , still the same error @Adi

Comment: strange, if it is in the first iteration: 1. Are you sure the new Rectangle is done before this for loop? what is the reason for the 'banks' loop? that value of j when the exception occur? also first iteration?